# Are there any tools for websites or app security scanning on Mac?

Tags: security, testing, security-testing

I want to do some security test for iOS app. There are some HTML5 pages in the app, so I want to do some security test such as network request, or others. I know there are many tools on Windows, but are there some tools on Mac? I also want to know the tools about scanning the app directly, are there?

Answer (score 0):

[Metasploit](http://www.metasploit.com/)  is a very good tools for mac to do penetration testing.
This is the most advanced and popular Framework that can be used to for pen-testing. It is based on the concept of ‘exploit’ which is a code that can surpass the security measures and enter a certain system. If entered, it runs a ‘payload’, a code that performs operations on a target machine, thus creating the perfect framework for penetration testing.